# Could I use QT dlls through delay-load or LoadLibrary?

Tags: windows, qt, delay-load

I'm working with a program using qt 5.6. Loading QT dlls(Qt5Core, Qt5Gui, Qt5Widgets etc.) makes my program occupying lot of memory space and it doesn't show UI all the time.
Could I use those Qt dlls through delay-load or use LoadLibrary?